# LightGBM model predicts infinite values

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, lightgbm

I have a real state dataset from Belgium ([available here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Joffreybvn/real-estate-data-analysis/master/data/clean/belgium_real_estate.csv)) and I want to use the LightGBM model for predicting the price column.

My code is as follows:

```
one_hot_state_of_the_building=pd.get_dummies(data.state_of_the_building) 
one_hot_city = pd.get_dummies(data.city_name, prefix='city')
one_hot_province = pd.get_dummies(data.province, prefix='province')
one_hot_region=pd.get_dummies(data.region, prefix ="region")
#removing categorical features 
data.drop(['city_name','state_of_the_building','province','region'],axis=1,inplace=True) 
 
#Merging one hot encoded features with our dataset 'data' 
data=pd.concat([data,one_hot_city,one_hot_state_of_the_building,one_hot_province,one_hot_region],axis=1) 
x=data.drop('price',axis=1) 
y=data.price 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=.3)

train_data=lgb.Dataset(x_train,label=y_train)

#setting parameters for lightgbm
hyper_params = {
    'task': 'train',
    'boosting_type': 'gbdt',
    'objective': 'regression',
    'metric': ['l1','l2'],
    'learning_rate': 0.005,
    'feature_fraction': 0.9,
    'bagging_fraction': 0.7,
    'bagging_freq': 10,
    'verbose': 0,
    "max_depth": 8,
    "num_leaves": 128,  
    "max_bin": 512,
    "num_iterations": 100000
}

gbm = lgb.LGBMRegressor(**hyper_params)


gbm.fit(x_train, y_train,
        eval_set=[(x_test, y_test)],
        eval_metric='l1',
        early_stopping_rounds=1000)


y_pred = gbm.predict(x_train, num_iteration=gbm.best_iteration_)


# Basic RMSE
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_log_error
print('The rmse of prediction is:', round(mean_squared_log_error(y_pred, y_train) ** 0.5, 5))
```

The RMSE is 0.19. When I run the following code:

```
test_pred = np.expm1(gbm.predict(x_test, num_iteration=gbm.best_iteration_))

x_test["Price"] = test_pred
x_test.to_csv("results.csv", columns=["Column1", "Price"], index=False)
```

I get a warning:

```
/tmp/ipykernel_50181/3204387303.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  x_test["Price"] = test_pred
```

and when I look at my "results.csv" file it's full of `Inf` in the predicted column.

Comment: Maybe you want `x_test = x_test.copy()` before modifying it.

Comment: that doesnt change the result

Comment: Yeah, that only helps the warning. The result is more of the model/data, not particularly pandas.

Comment: What exactly do you need an exponent of your predictions for? With an average value being over 300k, not even octuple precision would fit that.

Comment: good question, I based my experiment on this: https://www.kaggle.com/code/lasmith/house-price-regression-with-lightgbm

Comment: In that case you should set `y=np.log1p(data.price)` as they also do in cell 12 of the Kaggle notebook that you shared.